# How to find current input language

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a program that gets a process name, finds it's ID, 
and then finds the language with the function GetKeyboardLayout.

Although I'm having difficulties and it seem not to work. 
It finds the processID although the language that return is always 00000000.

That is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

DWORD FindProcessId(LPCTSTR ProcessName);

int main() {
    HKL currentKBLayout;
    DWORD processID;

    LPCTSTR processName = "chrome.exe";
    while (true) {
            processID = FindProcessId(processName);
            if (processID == 0); // TODO: pause system for 5 seconds
            else { 
                currentKBLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(processID);
                std::cout << processID << " | "<< currentKBLayout << std::endl;
            }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
DWORD FindProcessId(LPCTSTR ProcessName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
    HANDLE hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (Process32First(hsnap, &pt)) { // must call this first
        do {
            if (!lstrcmpi(pt.szExeFile, ProcessName)) {
                CloseHandle(hsnap);
                return pt.th32ProcessID;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hsnap, &pt));
    }
    CloseHandle(hsnap); // close handle on failure
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, [GetKeyboardLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout) accepts thread ID, not process ID.

Comment: As @AlgirdasPreidžius said, use the thread id (add `TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD`) instead.

Comment: hmmm , so how do I find the threadId then ?

Comment: You snapshot both processes and threads.

Comment: how do I do that ? 
It seem not to like the TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD
returns access violation error ...

Comment: You need to use the correct functions and structs, like. `Thread32First()`, `Thread32Next()` and `THREADENTRY32` [Traversing the Thread List](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/desktop/ToolHelp/traversing-the-thread-list)

Comment: If the target process has a visual UI (which it likely will if it is interacting with the keyboard), then instead of enumerating all threads on the entire system, it would be simpler to use `EnumWindows()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to find any `HWND`s that belong to the target process ID, and then you will have their owning thread IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Remys comment about using a simpler way to get the keyboard layout for the processes if that's all you need. If you however are interested in adding more information to your current approach using snapshots, this could be a way to start. It takes a snapshot of all processes and threads. Each `Process` has a `vector` of `Thread` objects. Adding `Thread` objects to each `Process` is done via an `unordered_map<processId, Process>`. To get a unique set of keyboard layouts for each process (since each thread may in theory have its own), an `unordered_set<HKL>` is used.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

struct Thread {
    DWORD m_id;
    HKL m_keyboard_layout;

    Thread(DWORD Id) :
        m_id(Id), m_keyboard_layout(GetKeyboardLayout(m_id))
    {}
};

struct Process {
    std::vector<Thread> m_threads;
    DWORD m_id;
    std::wstring m_exefile;

    Process() = default;
    Process(DWORD Id, std::wstring Name) :
        m_id(Id), m_exefile(Name) 
    {}

    // get a unique set of HKL:s from all the threads in the process 
    std::unordered_set<HKL> GetKeyboardLayouts() const {
        std::unordered_set<HKL> rv;
        for (auto& t : m_threads) {
            if(t.m_keyboard_layout) // does it have a keyboard layout?
                rv.emplace(t.m_keyboard_layout);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    // if you'd like to iterate over the individual threads
    std::vector<Thread>::iterator begin() { return m_threads.begin(); }
    std::vector<Thread>::iterator end() { return m_threads.end(); }
};

class Snapshot {
    HANDLE hSnap;
    std::unordered_map<DWORD, Process> m_processes;

    void GetProcesses() {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
        pt.dwSize = sizeof(pt);
        if (Process32First(hSnap, &pt)) { // must call this first
            do {
                m_processes[pt.th32ProcessID] = Process(pt.th32ProcessID, pt.szExeFile);
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &pt));
        }
    }

    void GetThreads() {
        THREADENTRY32 pt;
        pt.dwSize = sizeof(pt);
        if (Thread32First(hSnap, &pt)) { // must call this first
            do {
                m_processes[pt.th32OwnerProcessID].m_threads.emplace_back(pt.th32ThreadID);
            } while (Thread32Next(hSnap, &pt));
        }
    }

    void Populate() {
        GetProcesses();
        GetThreads();
    }
public:
    Snapshot() :
        hSnap(CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0)),
        m_processes()
    {
        // TODO: make this exception better
        if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) throw GetLastError();
        Populate();
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
    }

    std::unordered_map<DWORD, Process>::iterator begin() { return m_processes.begin(); }
    std::unordered_map<DWORD, Process>::iterator end() { return m_processes.end(); }
};

int main() {
    Snapshot snap;

    // show processes with keyboard layouts
    for (const auto& m : snap) { // std::pair  m.first = processId, m.second = Process

        const Process& p = m.second;    
        auto layouts = p.GetKeyboardLayouts();

        if (layouts.size()) { // only show processes with keyboard layouts
            std::wcout << p.m_id << L" " << p.m_exefile << L"\n";

            for (const auto& l : layouts) {
                std::wcout << L" layout " << l << L"\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note: When I ran this, I noticed that not all `chrome.exe` processes have a thread with a keyboard layout.